# Ionic [clear] property not working for a button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make a button transparent and Ionic docs say that the clear attribute does the trick. However, when I try it - it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<button *ngIf="showAddButton" [clear]="true" ion-button (click)="addButtonClicked()">
    <ion-icon  ios="ios-add" md="ios-add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: [`clear`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dlzk2j) will only make the border transparent. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make the background color of the button transparent

Comment: see here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tkzkfw

Comment: This is crazy. I see that it works in the link you provided. I literally copied one of your buttons in my project and it still shows blue background...

Comment: What elements wrap the button? Perhaps there is some conflicting CSS

Comment: Thank you for the useful information, still a mystery why it doesn't work though, just implemented it with CSS. Can't really post the code since it's confidential. Elements ion-grid and ion-row wrap the button.

Answer (score 1):

Add clear ass attribute

```
<button *ngIf="showAddButton" clear ion-button (click)="addButtonClicked()">
    <ion-icon  ios="ios-add" md="ios-add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

or with `attr`

```
[attr.clear]="true"
```

[doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#outline-buttons)

Comment: I don't think that would work - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tkzkfw

Answer (score 1):

Setting the  fill="clear" makes ion-button transparent.

```
  <ion-button
    expand="block"
    class="login-button"
    fill="clear"
    (click)="login()">
    Login
  </ion-button>
```